# How do I launch an external JAR, from another JAR, while setting the classpath?

Tags: java, applet, classpath, lwjgl, slick2d

I want to launch an external JAR, which I have the path of, stored in a string called *jarPath*. This external JAR, has multiple dependencies in another directory called natives.

How can I, within a Java Applet, swap to this JAR (as in swap the execution of the applet code, to my external JAR's code). The main class of the external JAR, is zombie.engine.Lighting2.

Comment: The dependencies are JARS, and native libraries used by LWJGL
The main class extends BasicGame, which is from another JAR called slick.jar. In the end, it uses OpenGL to create a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this launch I would recommend [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Natives are easy to deploy using JWS, as is adding other Jars to the run-time class-path.  Both applets and applications (`JFrame`, `JWindow` etc.) could be launched free-floating using JWS since its inception in 1.2, but from the Plug-In 2 architecture introduced in Sun's 1.6.0_10 JRE, it is possible to use JWS to deploy embedded applets.

Using this route to deploy, you would:

- Specify `zombie.engine.Lighting2` as the `main-class` (in the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) launch file).
- Add the dependent Jars using `jar` elements.
- Put the natives in the root of a Jar file (one Jar for each OS works best) and add them into an OS specific `resources` element.

The Jars with the natives as well as any other Jars referenced in the same JNLP will need to be digitally signed, and the JNLP request `all-permissions`.

---

> I want to be able to load the JAR offline, ..

See the `offline-allowed` element.

> `offline-allowed` element: The optional `offline-allowed` element indicates if the application can be launched offline.
>
> If offline-allowed is specified, then the application can be launched offline by the Java Application Cache Viewer, and shortcuts can be created which launch the application offline.

..from part of the [`information`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#information) element of the JNLP.

> ..I want to have a custom load screen,

JWS offers a simple GIF or JPEG based splash, but it seems like you are talking more about..

> .. which incorporates custom functions for downloading the core game and logging in the user.

An installer.  For installers, see the [`ExtensionInstallerService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).  Part of the [JNLP API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/).  Other things that installers might often need are the `DownloadService`/`DownloadService2` and the [`PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

Comment: I need it to be like the launcher of Minecraft, so no

Comment: What is the the launcher of minefcraft like?  In what way(s) does the JWS launch not equal it?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to load the JAR offline, I want to have a custom load screen, which incorperates custom functions for downloading the core game and logging in the user.

Comment: JWS can do all that with "one hand tied behind its back".  See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  exec(String command) of class java.lang.Runtime, the command to you pass is the java -jar /path_of_your_jar_app -classpath /path_of_the_classpat_library, maybe
 it's you need.